# c# Biblioteca de clases con implementacion de interfaces varias

Tags: c#, .net, interface

Muchachos, buenos días, estoy teniendo un problema, tengo una biblioteca de clases donde tengo diferentes interfaces y debería usar una u otra dependiendo de la versión que necesite.

Debería generar algo así pero no estoy pudiendo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No estoy pudiendo generar esa estructura
ya que las enumeraciones me quedan publicas desde la interface directamente.
Me está quedando así :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin duda estoy teniendo algún problema o en el espacio de nombres o en la declaración de las enumeraciones pero no puedo darme cuenta dónde está el error. Les dejo el código a ver si me pueden ayudar

INTERFACE

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PEPE2ApiParsing

{
    public interface IPEApiParsing_v0203
    {
    }

    public enum enumTipoDocumento
    {
        CI,
        PASAPORTE,
        DNI
    }

    public enum enumTipoPasaporte
    {
        NACIONAL,
        EXTRANJERO
    }

    public enum enumTipoMoneda
    {
        PESO,
        DOLAR
    }
}
```

CLASE

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PEPE2ApiParsing
{
    public class PEPE2ApiParsing : IPEApiParsing_v0203
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Estas queriendo obligar con la interface utilizar las enumeraciones y no las ves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luego de hacer algunas pruebas encontré la respuesta y confieso que es algo de lo que no tenía conocimiento. Para producir el resultado que esperas debes declarar los enumeradores dentro de la interface. (yo también me sorprendí)

Luego investigué un poco más y encontré [este artículo](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c1fb51/usage-of-class-and-enum-inside-an-interface/) bien interesante.

```
namespace PEPE2ApiParsing
{
    public interface IPEApiParsing_v0203
    {
        public enum enumTipoDocumento
        {
            CI,
            PASAPORTE,
            DNI
        }

        public enum enumTipoPasaporte
        {
            NACIONAL,
            EXTRANJERO
        }

        public enum enumTipoMoneda
        {
            PESO,
            DOLAR
        }
    }
}
```

`Imagen del resultado`

[image: Imagen del resultado]

Comment: Y porque no añadir miembros de tipo enumTipoDocumento, enumTipoPasaporte y enumTipoMoneda en tu interface en vez de declararlos adentro de la interface. Haz revisado si produce el mismo resultado.

Comment: @RichardValdivieso: Esa fue mi primera respuesta pero no produce el resultado requerido.